# Using "who" variable list to open cell array

Tags: matlab

I am trying to cycle through a list of variables I have say 30+ and calculate the maximum and minimum value for each column in each variable. Save this in a new array and then export to excel.

My thoughts were to use the who function to create an array with the name of all variables which are present. Then cycling through each one using a for loop after working out the size of the array which was created. This works fine, however when I try and use the string to reference the array it does not work.

I will add in the code which I have written hopefully someone will be able to come up with an easy solution :).

```
variable_list = who
cell2 = input('What cell size do you want to look at? ');
STARTcell = input('What was the start cell size? ');
[num_variables, temp] = size(variable_list);
for va = 1:num_variables
     variable = variable_list{va}    
     [max_value, max_index] = max(variable{cell2/STARTcell})
     [min_value, min_index] = min(variable{cell2/STARTcell})
     format_values{va} = vertcat(max_values, max_index, min_value, min_index);
end
```

The variables I am looking at are arrays which is why I use the cell2/STARTcell to reference them.

Comment: Why do you have 30 variables in the workspace in the first place? Did you create them with `eval()`? If yes, go back and create those variables as cells of a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `eval()` function to be able to get the value of a variable corresponding to a string. For example:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
variable_list = who;
c = eval(variable_list{2});
```

results in `c` being 2. In your code, the following line needs to change from:

```
variable = variable_list{va}
```

to:

```
variable = eval(variable_list{va});
```

resulting in `variable` having the value of the variable indicated by the string `variable_list{va}`. If `variable` is of `cell` type, then you should be fine, otherwise you may have to revise the next two lines of code as well because it seems that you are trying to access the content of a `cell`.